# why can we toggle a checkbox when its display property is none

Tags: html, css, forms, label

It looks like when checkbox is wrapped by a label element, we can still toggle it even if we have set the display property to none.

```css
label input {
  display: none;
}

label span.y {
  display: none;
}

label span.n {
  display: inline;
}

label input:checked~span.y {
  display: inline;
}

label input:checked~span.n {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="y">Checked!</span>
        <span class="n">Click me!</span>
</label>
```

it confuses me a lot, i'll appreciate it if you can explain it for me

Answer (score 1):

as per on [w3cschool](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) - label provides a usability improvement for **mouse** users, because if the user clicks on the text within the  **element**, it **toggles** the control.